# Open overlay pop-up every 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I looking to adv code like this page do : vozforums.com

They open a overlay pop-up every 15 minutes, use cookie. Here is screen shot :

[image]

I'm look in to they code and they using this pop-up code : http://defunkt.io/facebox/

But i'm do not know how to open pop-up every 15 minutes and just one-time per session (use jquery and cookie). So please help.

Comment: this will make user loathe your website, are you councious of that?

Answer (score 1):

A cookie can be set for a certain amount of time. You just need to check if the cookie exists, you shouldn't show the popup else show it and set the cookie.

```
if(readCookie('popupshown') == null)
{
  //show popup
}
```

methods for reading and setting cookies:

```
// Cookies
function createCookie(name, value, minutes) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";


    name = name;

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout and jQyeryUI Modal Dialog will do the trick for you.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
}, numberOfMSToWaitBeforeOpening);
```

You'll need to to a little coding around management of the timeout when they close the dialog if you want a recurrence of the popup.

Comment: there are page changes... settimeout will reset the timer for every page load.

Comment: That's not very clear from the question, besides not all sites do a reload for page changes, nowadays many use dynamic content loading.